# Is there any difference between "element:hover" and "element :hover"

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I was testing a `JQuery` code for dynamically appending `:hover` Css to `<head>`.

and I've found that there is difference in working of `element :hover` and `element:hover` (Note The Space)

That is, When I change `CSS` of `:hover` dynamically using `JQuery` like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("head").append("<style type='text/css'> 
                  .nav_menu li :hover{
                       background-color: red !important; 
                    } 
                   </style>");  // Code is formatted and trimmed for simplicity.
});
```

---

[FULL CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/wnx55o4m/)

---

If the Initial CSS has `element :hover` then it works fine.

That is If initial CSS is:

```
.nav_menu li :hover{
    background:#a55;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Then every thing works fine, and the output is like:

[image: "Initial Working output"]

Also you can see it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wnx55o4m/).

---

But if initially CSS is like `element:hover`
that is:

```
.nav_menu li:hover{
    background:#a55;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Then weird padding of initial background color occurs after `hovering` the element.

like:

[image: "Weird Behaviour"]

As you can see this version of `element:hover` doesn't work as expected. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnx55o4m/1/).

Also initial styling isn't rendered correctly in this.

---

So it is obvious and clear that there is difference between `element :hover` and `element:hover` (Note Space (`&nbsp;`)). or is it my browsers fault? tested it on `chrome` and `firefox`; same issue on both.

Can experts here, please clear this to me? thanks in advance.

PS:

I dont want to use `a:hover` in fact I'm here to know why is this happening.

Comment: Yes, spaces are meaningful in css selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference:

- `element:hover` applies the rules to the `element` when it is in the "hovered" state;
- `element :hover` applies the rules to *descendants* of the `element` when they are in the "hovered" state.

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time in answering this question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference. Its same as `element .div-class` and `element.div-class`. The second one will select `.div-class` that is the class of `element`, First one will select `.div-class` that is the child of `element`

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time in answering this.

Answer (score 2):

**YES!** There is a difference.

`element:hover` applies to the `element` itself when it's in the **hover** state.

`element :hover` applies to child elements of that `element` when any of them are in the **hover** state.

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time in answering this.

Comment: That should be "descendant elements", not "child elements". :)

Comment: "descendant" and "child" has the same meaning in English. I'm not talking about immediate childs though :)

Comment: @aniskhan001: Not quite. In English, when referring to offspring, "child" and "immediate child" would have the same meaning. Although nobody would use "immediate child" to refer to offspring. :)